# Getting "FAILED: Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list" when passing the list from the command line

Tags: ansible

**Purpose**: I would like to define a set of Host IPs in the inventory file and pass those Host IPs and a list of IP addresses of the files that should be deleted from the remote server.

**Example**:

```shell
sudo ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt -k -K delete_file_task.yml --extra-vars "10.48.194.248=['10.10.10.2','10.10.10.3'] 192.168.1.89=['10.10.10.61,'10.10.10.62','192.10.10.63'] 10.99.194.250=['10.10.10.64,'10.10.10.65','10.10.10.66']"
```

**Expected Outcome**:
The IP address file names are deleted from the remote server.

**Actual Issue**:
Files are not deleted from the remote server(s).

**Command**:

```shell
sudo ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt -k -K delete_file_task.yml --extra-vars "files_to_delete={'10.48.194.248': ['10.10.10.2','10.10.10.3','10.10.10.4']}"
```

**Output**:

```yaml
SSH password:
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]:
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.48.194.248]

TASK [Delete file] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item={)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=')
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=1)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=0)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=.)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=4)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=8)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=.)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=1)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=9)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=4)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=.)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=2)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=4)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=8)
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=')
ok: [10.48.194.248] => (item=:)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.48.194.248              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The **inventory** file looks like this:

```ini
cat inventory.txt
[aatestgroup01]
10.48.194.248
<Second Host IP>
<Third Host IP>
```

The **Ansible playbook** looks like this:

```yaml
cat delete_file_task.yml
---
- name: Delete temp files
  hosts: aatestgroup01
  remote_user: L3support
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Delete file
      file:
        path: "/tmp/{{ item }}.db.json"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ files_to_delete | list }}"
...
```

Comment: Do I read correctly between the lines that you do want to remove the files `10.10.10.{2..4}` from the host `10.48.194.248` and that you intend to pass, `{ host1-IP: [list-of-files-to-delete-on-host1], host2-IP: [list-of-files-to-delete-on-host2], ... }`? If so, please mind to always point at what you want to achieve in your question, as failing to do so would lead you in [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=xy+problem&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) situations.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I apologize, but that is what I have asked in the question. Please edit so I get an insight so I can improve next time. I tried the solution proposed, but it is not working. I did try dic, from_yaml after pipe but none of them worked.

Comment: Easy for bad actors to down vote, hard to ask for clarification and help someone cross?

Answer (score 1):

You can do following:

```yaml
---
- name: Delete the stale IPs of cameras
  hosts: aatestgroup01
  remote_user: L3support
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Delete file
      file:
        path: "/tmp/{{ item }}.db.json"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ files_to_delete | list }}"
```

**Explanation**

- `list` filter will convert the above IP Addresses into a valid list for `loop` directive.

Comment: get a new error no
fatal: [10.48.194.248]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'unicode object' has no attribute 'keys'"}

Comment: no luck still...

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes from the fromat of the 'files_to_delete' variable passed as an extra variable.It needs to ve a dictionary with keys as the hostname and values as a list of files to delete on that host.

You can change `files_to_delete` like this:

```
{
    '10.48.194.248': ['10.10.10.2', '10.10.10.3', '10.10.10.4']
}
```

If you have multiple hosts, the `files_to_delete` variable should have multiple keys for each host and their corresponding list of files to delete.

```
{
    'hostname1': ['file1', 'file2', ...],
    'hostname2': ['file1', 'file2', ...],
    ...
}
```

After modify the format of the extra variable, run the playbook with following command:

```
sudo ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt -k -K delete_file_task.yml --extra-vars "files_to_delete={'10.48.194.248': ['10.10.10.2','10.10.10.3','10.10.10.4']}"
```